# Get Document source After AJAX or js Action With PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, dom, file-get-contents

When I compare the source code of a webpage in the browser with the source code I get from the code below,

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://www.someurl.com/loader.aspx");
```

it differs. The source code is not the same and I suspect that is caused because of some DOM manipulations.

Is it possible to get the HTML source code after the javascript and/or ajax manipulations programmaticly (with PHP)?

Comment: @jszobody No it doesn't, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: i want get the source code of that webpage  and save it in varible with php 
with file-get-contents some html code that generated with js or ajax not recive

Comment: i want write some php script that's get source code of that site after all js or ajax effect ...

Comment: @MOB Did you look at my answer? `file_get_contents` will NOT evaluate Javascript code on the page, you have to use a third-party headless browser.

Comment: yes ... know see ... can show me some example ... thanx a lot

Comment: @MOB I included a link to https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs in my answer. All the example code you need is right there. Full instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a headless browser that can evaluate JavaScript on the page. One very popular option is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Then look at [PHP PhantomJS](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs) to see how you can control this headless browser from your PHP scripts.

Comment: unfortunately i cant use PHP PhantomJS for my work ... 
can help me for use this source and install it 
when i call PHP PhantomJS below err accourd
Fatal error: Class 'JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\read\test\src\a.php on line 4